# What type of objects a block will retain in the closure?

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I say which type of objects a closure will retain? Is there any particular rule or list of types that closure will/will not retain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Objective-C objects are retained. Everything else is simply copied. For example, here are three variables:

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray array];
int i = 0;
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

All three variables can be **read** from inside a block. However, only `array` will be retained, since it is the only variable on which it's possible to call the `retain` method.

Special care should be taken to make sure that the place `ptr` points to still exists when the block is executed, since it is a pointer that cannot be retained.

Comment: if I have `int i` and `int *i`, both will retain? How can I distinguish between Obj-C and non-Obj-C object?

Comment: @Michael, Objective-C objects are values on which you can call Objective-C methods. For instance, if you have a `NSString` called `foo`, you can call `[foo retain]`. If you can't do something like that, it's not an Objective-C object. I've edited my answer.